# Android - Toolbar and TabLayout scroll if drag them up/down

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-tablayout

How to avoid scrolling of Toolbar and TabLayout by dragging them ? In my example I have such main.xml

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarMain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="1dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

ViewPager contains fragment with recycleview. The problem is that I can scroll Toolbar and TabLayout by dragging them up and down even if recycleview is not instantiated. I want that Toolbar and TabLayout scroll only when I scroll recycleview. Do you have any ideas how to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

In your activity class, you can put:

```
tabLayout.setClickable(false);
```

or

```
tabLayout.setEnabled(false);
```

And only enable again in the condition that you want.

Comment: I set it but Toolbar and TabLayout still scroll. Any other ideas ?